# Oracle SQL take id when its has different values

Tags: sql, oracle

```
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| ID       | date_value          | value |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:05 | 150   |
| 1        | 2011-04-20 21:03:04 | 150   |
| 2        | 2011-04-20 21:03:03 | 20    |
| 2        | 2011-04-20 21:02:09 | 130   |
| 2        | 2011-04-20 21:02:08 | 130   |
| 3        | 2011-04-20 21:02:07 | 20    |
| ...      | ...                 | ...   |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
```

With this table how could I find, using a select, the IDs that have more than 2 values above 100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, count(*) from mytable
WHERE value > 100
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(*) >2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below

```
select id,count(value)
from table1
where value > 100
having count(value) > 2
group by ID;
```

Comment: Doesn't the HAVING clause have to come after the GROUP BY?

Comment: it can come before also

Comment: Interesting - that works in Oracle, but it would cough in Postgresql. Thanks - I learned something!

Comment: @psaraj12 the having clause will not work as you stated as mlinth says

Comment: HI @Sudharsanan, psaraj is right, it works in Oracle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188862/oracle-sql-select-syntax-with-group-by-and-having-clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, count(1)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  value > 100
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(1) > 2;
```